# How do I call a certain Episodes in a Genre

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I am getting confused over that, basically I want to iterate through all of the series and return the ones that are in certain genre.

**models.py**

```
class Series(models.Model):
    series_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    series_desc = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    series_date_published = models.DateTimeField()

class Genres(models.Model):
    genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre_serie = models.ManyToManyField(Series)

class Episodes(models.Model):
    episode_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    episode_desc = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    episode_date_published = models.DateTimeField()
    episode_number = models.IntegerField()
    episode_series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Series
    template_name = 'videos/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'series'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Series.objects.all()

class ViewSeries(generic.ListView):
    model = Episodes
    template_name = 'videos/videos.html'
    context_object_name = 'episodes'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Episodes.objects.filter(episode_series=self.kwargs['pk'])

class ViewGenres(generic.ListView):
    model = Series
    template_name = 'videos/genres.html'
    context_object_name = 'series'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Series.objects.filter(genres__genre_serie=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

And I am trying that to display my series in a genre:

```
{% for s in series %}
  <a href='(% url ?? %)'>{{ s.series_title }}</a></td>      
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
app_namme = 'videos'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    path('viewseries/<int:pk>', ViewSeries.as_view(),name='detail'),
    path('viewgenres/<int:pk>', ViewGenres.as_view(),name='genres'),
]
```

I placed that url because from there I want to get the link to the series but when I type `{% url 'detail' ser.id %}` I got NoReverseMatch error.

I am pretty sure that there is an easy solution to all of that and I am doing it really complex that is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here: (1) getting the series that belong to a certain genre; and (2) correcting the `{% url ... %}` lookup:

We can do this by exploiting the *reverse* relation of a `ManyToManyField` (this is - if no reverse name is provided - the `modelname`):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Series.objects.filter(genre__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).distinct()
```

Then for the `{% url ... %}` part, you probably need to provide a *named* parameter (also the `url` needs to be placed between *curly* brackets, not round ones, so:

```
{% for s in series %}
  <td><a href="{% url 'videos:detail' pk=s.pk %}">{{ s.series_title }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you it all worked! I thought that I should call for the foreign key in order to get all the series. And one more thing that I noticed, I just had misspelled the `app_namme = 'videos'`